# Problemas instanciando clases con parámetros

Tags: java, jdbc

Tengo un programa en java que tiene varias clases-objetos. Una de ellas tiene parámetros declarados en el constructor:

```
public class Venta {
    private String marca;
    private String modelo;
    public Venta(String mc, String mod) {
        marca = mc;
        modelo = mod;
    }
    public String getMarca() {
        return marca;
    }
    public void setMarca(String marca) {
        this.marca = marca;
    }
    public String getModelo() {
        return modelo;
    }
    public void setModelo(String modelo) {
        this.modelo = modelo;
    }
```

Después hago una consulta en una base de datos en otra clase y necesito ingresar los valores obtenidos a la clase Venta:

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class ConectaDB {
    ArrayList<Venta> datos = new ArrayList();
    public void LlenarDatos() {
        try {
            DriverManager.registerDriver(new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("driver@machineName:port:SID", "userid", "password");
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select * from VENTA");
            while (rset.next())
            for (int x=1; x<=rset.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); x++) {
                Venta venta = new Venta();
                venta.setMarca(rset.getString("MARCA"));
                venta.setModelo(rset.getString("MODELO"));
                datos.add(venta);
            }
            rset.close();
            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Finalmente muestro los datos en:

```
public class Resultado {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Venta venta = new Venta();
        System.out.print(venta.getMarca());
        System.out.print(venta.getModelo());
    }
}
```

Pero el programa no me permite compilar y me muestra un error cada vez que quiero instanciar la clase Venta. Este es el mensaje:

```
Constructor Venta in class Venta cannot be applied to given types;   
required: String, String   
found: no arguments reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Creo que es porque esta clase en su constructor tiene parámetros.
Como puedo solucionar este problema para instanciar la clase venta?

Comment: Tu dices: *... me muestra un error cada vez que quiero instanciar la clase Venta. ...* pero no nos dices que mensaje es. Los mensajes de error son valiosos asi que necesitamos que lo añadas a tu pregunta.

Comment: Añadelo a tu pregunta.

Comment: Alguna novedad :P

Comment: bueno mi consejo para que sea mas facil , si quieres llamar una propiedad desde otra clase te recomiendo que las crees como "protected"

Comment: @Gilberto por que protected? Me parece que tu consejo es erroneo. las propiedades protected solo sirven para que las clases que heredan puedan sobreescribirlas, ya que las propiedades privadas no se las puede modificar desde una clase hija.

Comment: lo se bueno yo entendi que su pregunta era sobre "clases que heredan" pero ya viendo bien la pregunta ,ya vi mi error

Comment: Puedes crear un constructor que no reciba valores y pasárselos a través de los métodos set como haces ahora, simplemente tendrías que quitar los parámetros que le pasas al constructor de la clase Ventas y ya lo tienes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema que tienes surge al redefinir/sobrecargar el constructor por defecto por el siguiente:

```
public Venta(String mc, String mod) {
    marca = mc;
    modelo = mod;
}
```

Al añadir este constructor y solo este, provocas que para crear una venta **siempre** tengas que invocarlo por `new Venta(String, String)` pasándole los parámetros correspondientes y esto en tu código nunca lo haces.

> Añade nuevamente el constructor por defecto `public Venta(){}` y tu problema debería estar solucionado. En la clase "ConectaDB", cada vez que creas una
>   "Venta" estas intentado utilizar el constructor por defecto que atualmente no existe, tienes que crearlo.

Tu clase quedaría de esta manera:

```
public class Venta {
    private String marca;
    private String modelo;
    public Venta(){} //CONSTRUCTOR POR DEFECTO.
    public Venta(String mc, String mod) {
        marca = mc;
        modelo = mod;
    }
    ......
```

> La otra alternativa es añadir los parámetros siempre que crees una
>   nueva venta:

```
for (int x=1; x<=rset.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); x++) {
       Venta venta = new Venta();
       venta.setMarca(rset.getString("MARCA"));
       venta.setModelo(rset.getString("MODELO"));
       datos.add(venta);
}
```

El código anterior es el que utilizas actualmente, para utilizar el constructor sobrecargado que ya tienes cambialo por:

```
for (int x=1; x<=rset.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); x++) {
     // Haz las comprobaciones que te sean necesarias.
     Venta venta = new Venta(rset.getString("MARCA"), rset.getString("MODELO"));
     datos.add(venta);
}
```

Con estos dos casos das por solucionados tus problemas, espero que te sean de ayuda.

Enlaces de ejemplos:

https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructor_(inform%C3%A1tica)

https://java-white-box.blogspot.com.es/2013/12/javaplayer-constructores-en-java-que-es.html

**--EDICIÓN--**

Ahora el problema que tienes es otro, para extraer los datos de la BBDD, primero asegurate de que se conecta correctamente, luego [extrae la información](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/es/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_tjvstxqu.html) de tu consulta:

En tu select por depuración del código añade los nombres de las columnas separados por comas `(SELECT NOMBRE_EXACTO_DE_TU_COLUMNA, OTRO_NOMBRE FROM TU_TABLA)` y luego:

```
int campo = rs.getInt("NOMBRE_EXACTO_DE_TU_COLUMNA");
System.out.println(campo + "\t" + otrosCampo);
```

Comment: OK pero el problema final es como imprimo los datos obtenidos de la base de datos. He intentado con esto:   `public static void main(String[] args) {
            ConectaDB datos = new ConectaDB();    
          ArrayList<ConectaDB> dts;
        System.out.print(dts.get(0).toString() + "</br>");
        System.out.print(dts.get(1).toString());
    }    `  utilizando el arraylis de la clase conectaDB, pero no logro obtener los datos

Comment: He editado la respuesta, mira si con esto solucionas el nuevo problema que tienes.

Comment: Con eso queda el problema solucionado. Una última cosa, si quisiera ocupar esta variable campo en otra clase(objeto), tendría que declararla como pública en esta clase (ConectaDB) verdad?

Comment: a que te refieres por ocupar? Si a utilizarla desde otra clase te refieres, declara los metodos set y gets para ArrayList<Venta> datos = new ArrayList(); de manera que cuando crees a conectaDB luego puedas hacer un ConectaDB  cdb= new ConectaDB(); cdb.getDatos() en cualquier punto del aplicativo.

Comment: Gracias @UHDante, ahora me queda más claro

Answer (score 0):

para instanciar la clase Venta necesitas parametros

tu codigo `Venta venta = new Venta();`

debes poner parametros `Venta venta = new Venta(mc, mod);`

Comment: Lo intenté pero muestra esto: `cannot find symbol`; es porque los atributos marca y modelo están declarados como privados.

Comment: @virtual8870 debes poner valores, suple con valores a los parametros mc y mod

Comment: x-rw no logro entender, con valores te refieres a declarar otras variables o algo así?

Comment: @virtual8870 asi  new Venta("lipsum","Toyota");

Comment: pero esos valores serían string, verdad?

Comment: @virtual8870 exactamente!!!